# Manipulate html response in Android-Java

Tags: java, android, html

i have the response from website, in html, i have put this in String variable, now for example i want to color all tag "table" in red, i try with this:

```
String s = "<font color='#FF0000'><b>table</b></font>";
Spanned text =  Html.fromHtml(s);

rowID=rowID.replace("table",text);
responseView.setText(rowID);
```

but not works..how i can to manipulate it? there is a library to help me?, the problem is because i put the manipulate response in a TextView ?

Comment: ok sorry..but the problem still going.. because if i try String s = "<font color='#FF0000'><b>table</b></font>";
Spanned text =  Html.fromHtml(s); responseView.setText(rowID);  works very well :)  but with this rowID=rowID.replace("table",text); not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `responseView.setText(Html.fromHtml(rowID), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);`

Comment: works but i must delete this:  Spanned text =  Html.fromHtml(s);